# CSS strange DIV alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue aligning a DIV inside a DIV wrapper using

> display: inline-block

in the content DIV and

> text-align: center

in the wrapper.

It seems the following any content DIV actually contains content, the following DIV aligns at the bottom of the former's text.

The CSS:

```
.kbWrapper{
    text-align:center;
}

.kbColumn{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #303030;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.kbColumn h4{
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 24px Arial, Helvetica;
    color: #303030;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.kbColumn hr{

}

.kbColumn ul{
    font: bold 22px Arial, Helvetica;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.kbColumn ul li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.kbColumn ul li a{
    color: #1589FF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.kbCategory{    
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #EE33EE;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<body>

<div id='page'>
    <h1 id='pageTitle'>Knowledge Base</h1>
    <div id='pageDescription'>
    <p>I cannot get this to line up correctly.</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class='kbWrapper'>

    <div class='kbColumn'>
        <h4>First</h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='kbColumn'>
        <h4>Second</h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='kbColumn'>
        <h4>Third</h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='kbColumn'>
        <h4>Fourth</h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>
        <li class='hvr-grow'><a target='_parent' href='/knowledgebase.php?faq=6'>This is a great day?</a></li>
        <li class='hvr-grow'><a target='_parent' href='/knowledgebase.php?faq=5'>Are they available in pink?</a></li>
        <li class='hvr-grow'><a target='_parent' href='/knowledgebase.php?faq=4'>What type of food do you like?</a></li>
        <li class='hvr-grow'><a target='_parent' href='/knowledgebase.php?faq=3'>How heavy is a bucket of water?</a></li>
        <li class='hvr-grow'><a target='_parent' href='/knowledgebase.php?faq=1'>What color is an alligator?</a></li>       </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='kbColumn'>
        <h4>Fifth</h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='kbColumn'>
        <h4>Sixth</h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>
        <li class='hvr-grow'><a target='_parent' href='/knowledgebase.php?faq=2'>What is today?</a></li>        </ul>
    </div>
    </div><!--kbWrapper-->


</div>

</body>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/s10jam/nb77qvge/) is what I'm seeing. Any thoughts?

Comment: so what is your expected result.? do you expecting like this.? **https://jsfiddle.net/nb77qvge/1/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this style in your class :

```
.kbColumn {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the all boxes in same alignment, please try this i hope it will helpful to you...

```css
.kbColumn{
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
 width: 350px;
 height: 300px;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 border: 2px solid #303030;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. The example you provided does not seem to work. Kushal's answer solved my issue though. Thank you for the response.